# Why does highlighting in the soul package change the spacing between letters?

Tags: highlighting, soul

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color, soul}

% comment out one of the two: 
\newcommand{\myhl}[1]{\hl{#1}} % highlight
%\newcommand{\myhl}[1]{{#1}}      % don't highlight

\soulregister\cite7
\soulregister\ref7
\soulregister\eqref7
\soulregister\pageref7
```

From the code, to highlight a sentence, I typed as follows

```
\myhl{sentence ABCDE.}
```

The inter-letter spacing of some sentences does not change whether using `myhl` function or not.
However, the inter-letter spacing of some sentences changes when using `myhl` function.
Why does this situation occur?
How can I avoid from the change in the inter-letter spacing?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you for your good comment.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes no, `\hl` uses (stretchable) leaders, so that wouldn't explain the difference. @Danny_Kim care to show a real MWE?

Comment: @Robert Sorry, what is the MWE?

Comment: One common reason are wider spaces at the end of a sentence. E.g. `Hello there. What's up?` will have a wider space between `there.` and `What's` then between `Hello` and `there`. This is implemented using spacefactors which are not preserved by soul, so in `\myhl{Hello there. What's up?}` all spaces are the same, leading to differences.

Comment: @Robert Thank you...I will delete my comment

Comment: [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/7674): a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, showing the problem you experience.

Comment: if you want us to debug something then you need to supply a test file that shows the problem